# Is request order garenteed in web api?

Tags: asp.net-core, httprequest, asp.net-core-webapi

I made a web api with asp core.
When a client sends two requests in a row, A and B. Is the order of requests guaranteed as with TCP protocol?
Can I be sure the request A is always processed before request B in my web api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't be sure that the first request is processed before the second one as the requests could be handled by different threads, so there's no guarantee about the order you'll receive your responses.
If you want to be sure to display data related only to your last request, you could use a counter on the client side, increment that at every request and send it to your API. On the server side, the response will then contains your counter and your client will only show the response that has the matching counter in the content.